# Saved model in R software show error in loading

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I trained a svm model using `caret` package. I saved the trained model in my folder. However, at some point when I load this model, the follow error occurs:

```
source(submission) : model.Data:158:8: unexpected symbol 157: 158: Kernel Method ^ in R
```

Submission is my folder and model and trained model is my object.

The code employed to save model is:

```
setwd(submissionDir)
save(model,file="model.RData")
```

Has someone already saw this error? If anyone can help be, I will be grateful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you used `save()` to save the model, you should use `load()` to restore that object, not `source()`. `source()` is for running a text file that contains R code.

Comment: Also, in the future, if you are just saving one model it is worth looking into `saveRDS` and `readRDS`.